# onblur and onfocus event in jquery sometime don't work properly on IE browser

Tags: jquery, razor

I am using onblur and onfocus event to call function to toggle textbox type as Password or Text.

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FinanceModel.VatNumber, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control capitalize", maxlength = 30, @onblur = "setTypePassword(this);", @onfocus = "setTypeText(this);" })

Changes working fine on Chrome browser but sometime it is not working fine on IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not allow you to change the attribute type of an input field.
But you can keep two input one with type="password" and other type="text"
and then show hide then on focus and blur event & it works in all browsers along with IE :-).